# How do I write script in React index.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

I've been using basic HTML/CSS/JS so far, and now I tried using React/Gatsby.
I got API code from Kakao and confirmed the following code is working in index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:500px;"></div>

    <script src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608"></script>
    <script>{
      var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOption = {
          center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56591, 126.97894),
          level: 4,
          mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

      var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption);

    }</script>
</body>
```

Since I'm trying React/Gatsby framework, I have to somehow reformat that script to index.js. HTML can be easily copy/pasted to return function, but I don't know how to write the above script in React index.js.

```
import React from "react"

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ color: `purple` }}>
      <p>Welcome to donghwankim.com!</p>
      <p>Powered by Gatsby</p>
      <div id="map" style={{"height" : "1000px", "width" : "500px"}}></div>

      <script src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608"></script>
      <script>{
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'), 
          mapOption = {
            center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56591, 126.97894), 
            level: 4, 
            mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
          };

        var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption);

      }</script>
    </div>
  )}
}
```

Few things I tried:

1. Just copy paste script like above. In this case, I get syntax error from the copied script:

> Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?

2. Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. There is no syntax error, but the map API is not working properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like part of this script will need to be rewritten for React. You should look for a library for this that supports React. If there isn't one, you can use [DOM refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access the `mapContainer` without `document.getElementById`. Alternatively if you just want to use this script as-is, you can use a simpler static site generator like Jekyll that doesn't require you to use React.

Answer (score 2):

### 2022 update

Since the release of the [`Script` Gatsby component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/) (powered by Partytown) it's much easier adding third-party scripts. Just:

```
import React from "react"
import { Script } from "gatsby"

function YourPage() {
  return <Script src="https://my-example-script" />
}

export default YourPage
```

---

There's a lot of implementation there.

First of all, you need to load your script asynchronously using `<Helmet>` tag by using:

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {

  return (
    <div style={{ color: `purple` }}>
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608" type="text/javascript"/>
      </Helmet> 
      <p>Welcome to donghwankim.com!</p>
      <p>Powered by Gatsby</p>
      <div id="map" style={{"height" : "1000px", "width" : "500px"}}></div>
    </div>
  )}
}
```

Because of the asynchronous of your issue, you need to load a `<div>` container for your map and wait for its load, then you need to pass your map options. The preferred method in React, rather than `document.getElementById` (or similar), what retrieve directly values from the DOM, is using references. You'll need to use a `componentDidMount()` lifecycle to achieve it, since it's a method invoked that triggers immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree):

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
 
  componentDidMount(){
  const map= this.myRef.current;
  const mapOption = {
    center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56591, 126.97894), 
    level: 4, 
    mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
  };

  const yourMap = new kakao.maps.Map(map, mapOption);
 }

  render() {

  return (
    <div style={{ color: `purple` }}>
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608" type="text/javascript"/>
      </Helmet> 
      <p>Welcome to donghwankim.com!</p>
      <p>Powered by Gatsby</p>
      <div id="map" ref={this.myRef}  style={{"height" : "1000px", "width" : "500px"}}></div>
    </div>
  )}
}
```

*Note: you may need to unmount the map to avoid excessive resource consumption. It depends on how the library is implemented and its documentation.*

Recommended readings/references:

- https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet
- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount
- https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must add that I forgot to remove line: const myExtScript = require('../scripts/kakaomap'). My mistake from changing over and over. sorry.

Comment: I ran your solution, and I get "13:17  error    'kakao' is not defined                        no-undef" error while Generating development JavaScript bundle. I actually had the same problem before too, but didn't know how to fix it. Do you know how to resolve this error? Thank you. @Ferran Buireu